# Auto Login after Registration

Tags: wordpress, registration, autologin

I am using `custom registration form` and users are registered when they `sign up`.

Now, what I really want to do is **users** are *redirected* to their `profile page` with **`auto_logged in`** after `registration` is complete. I searched for a  few solutions on **strong text**stack overflow but none helped me.

**Here's my registration `snippet`**

> Note: registration form is not included here

```
$err = '';
$success = '';
global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'register' ) {
    $pwd1 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['pwd1']));
    $pwd2 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['pwd2']));
    $first_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['first_name']));
    $last_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['last_name']));
    $email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email']));
    $username = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['user_name']));

        $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('first_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name), 'last_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name), 'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
        if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $err = 'Error on user creation.';
        } else {
            do_action('user_register', $user_id);

            $success = 'You\'re successfully register';

        }               
}
```

**Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a action "user_register" when successfully registration completed so using this hook to when user register complete then it will be auto login like this:

```
// It is login system same as wordpress and also global variable available like $current_user etc.

add_action('user_register', "auto_login_after_register");

function auto_login_after_register( $user_id ){
  global $wpdb;
  if(  'post' ==  strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ){
     $pwd1 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['pwd1']));
     $username = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['user_name']));  
     $creds = array();
     $creds['user_login'] = $username;
     $creds['user_password'] = $pwd1;
     $creds['remember'] = false;
     $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
     if ( ! is_wp_error($user) ){
        wp_redirect( admin_url('profile.php') );
        exit;
     }
  } 
}
```

Or put code without action

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('first_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name), 'last_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name), 'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
        if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $err = 'Error on user creation.';
        } else {
            do_action('user_register', $user_id);
            $creds = array();
                 $creds['user_login'] = $username;
                 $creds['user_password'] = $pwd1;
                 $creds['remember'] = false;
                 $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
                 if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
                      $err = $user->get_error_message();
                 }else{
                    $login_redirect = apply_filters( 'login_redirect', admin_url('profile.php') ); 
                    wp_redirect( $login_redirect );
                    exit;
                 }
            $success = 'You\'re successfully register';

        }
```

Comment: I tried second option and it is redirecting to `login-page`, but user doesn't get `logged-in`. User has to enter their `username` and `passwords`

Comment: check put in wp_redirect( admin_url('profile.php') );

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. Forgot to use `wp_signon` function. Actually, I wanted to redirect to `homepage` with `logged-in` and it's working. Thanks to you. However, Can you help me on small issue. While redirecting to homepage, the user will see popup or some message on header that he/she has successfully registered. But only for registered user, not for other existing users while login in.

Comment: you can pass query parameter when redirect to home page and check query parameter or show message 
$login_redirect = http://www.example.com?login=success
wp_redirect( $login_redirect );

Comment: yes, but the question is how to display message on certain parameters only. I mean I only want to display modal for example.com?login=success  this parameter. I think you get it what I mean right ?

Comment: yes you can check in home page using php $_GET['login'] == 'success' and show your custom message if found in get login param

Answer (score 2):

#### First, add this function to `functions.php`:

```
function so37068411_wp_auto_login($username, $useremail, $userpwd) {

    if ( empty($username)
    || empty($useremail)
    || empty($userpwd) )
    return; // better to send out a message.

    $username  = sanitize_user($username);
    $useremail = sanitize_email($useremail);
    $userpwd   = sanitize_user($userpwd);

    if ( username_exists($username) ) {
        // do something.
    }

    $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $userpwd, $useremail);

    if ($user_id) {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
        wp_redirect( admin_url('profile.php') );
        exit;
    } else {
        // do something.
    }

}
```

You can add other validations. It depends on your form fields.

#### Second, create a test page template:

```
/**
 * Template Name: Registration Page
 */
if ( isset($_POST['submit-btn']) ) {
    so37068411_wp_auto_login($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_pwd'], $_POST['user_email']);
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>WordPress Deployment &lsaquo; Registration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= admin_url('load-styles.php?c=1&amp;dir=ltr&amp;load%5B%5D=dashicons,buttons,forms,l10n,login&amp;ver=4.5.2') ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body class="login login-action-register wp-core-ui locale-en-us">
<div id="login">
  <form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="" method="post" novalidate>
    <p>
      <label for="user_name">Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="user_name" class="input" value="" size="20" />
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="user_email">Email<br />
        <input type="email" name="user_email" class="input" value="" size="25" />
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pwd">Password<br />
        <input type="text" name="user_pwd" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="submit-btn" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Register" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, create a page by using that template and check it out. The form is minimal for demo purpose, you can modify it on your own. Make sure to do validation and sanitization securely.

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in your functions.php file.

```
 <?php
    function tml_new_user_registered( $user_id ) {
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'profile.php' ) );
        exit;
    }
    add_action( 'tml_new_user_registered', 'tml_new_user_registered' );
    ?>
```

I hope this will work for you.Thanks

Comment: well , that's a `code` for `Default` WordPress registration form. but I have `Custom Registration Form` buddy.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8998/user-registration-followed-by-automatic-login.   refer this link

Comment: well that's for sending `user_details` to newly registered users by mailing them. Not exactly what i'm looking for. I just want to `autologin` and returning to homepage.